# new google script version throwing javascript error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Script-JSON-javascript webapp working but when I changed the JSON output, saved a new Google Script version, and published as web app, the webpage throws a CORB error.

Going back a version in GS, allowed it to work again. Why would a new GS version cause an error. Even with the same code but in a new version the error is still thrown. Is there a GS version caching issue? What I can do to update the version?

Working page with current version: https://arcacademy.ca/arc-academy-calendar-2018-2019/

**Note: You can see in Console the JSON text being sent. The new code has the same format/structure, except changed the color values from hex to 1 to 10.**

To tried to fix this by creating a new GS script but receive the same error:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyM51kxwQOYM3hRyrW7semhmUka2z2w-jU09KBPL38IxKapeQQ1/exec?callback=receivedCalendarEvents
>   with MIME type text/html. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Here's the **not working page** throwing above error in console: https://arcacademy.ca/clone-of-arc-academy-calendar-2018-2019/

Google Script web app deployed with:

- Execute as Me
- Anyone, even Anonymous

Google Script code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.method=="populate_events") {
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var calendarId = scriptProperties.getProperty('calendarId') || 'primary';
    var v = extractCalendarDateColors( calendarId, e.year );

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(v) + ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
  }
}
```

Javascript code for working page (src= is the only thing changed for error page):

```
<script>
calendarEvents = {};
function receivedCalendarEvents(jsonData) {
console.log('received',jsonData);
calendarEvents = JSON.parse(jsonData);
}
</script>
<script src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzMCDiTzxGx2cN5dtXqCG2gvxJ6FGZ_t6UuPiT-HyDesu2--EY/exec?callback=receivedCalendarEvents"></script>
<script>
```

Google Console Cloud -- I have set the following:

- Enabled Calendar API
- Added Apps Script Client ID

I feel like I'm lost in Google access land. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? The script in your question is the modified one? Namely, it's the script of "not work page"? Although I'm not sure whether this directly leads to the solution, can you provide the scripts of both before and after the script was modified?

Comment: If the script of your question is the script of "not work page", how about this modification? In your "not working page", the endpoint using at the fetch is ``https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec?callback=receivedCalendarEvents``. But in your question, your script of Web Apps doesn't return values by ``if (e.parameter.method=="populate_events") {}``. Actually, ``The script completed but did not return anything.`` is returned. So when the endpoint is modified to ``https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec?method=populate_events``, will be the situation modified?

Comment: As an additional report, when I tried to do it in my environment, the script error occurs when the query is used. It's ``Error: no such calendar: #####@group.calendar.google.com :: RangeError: Date is invalid. (line 66, file &quot;Code&quot;, project &quot;Arc Public Calendar v8&quot;)``. So please confirm about the script you modified again. Also we cannot see about ``extractCalendarDateColors()``.

Comment: The javascript above is from the working page. Excellent point about adding the parameters. I have updated the webpages to reflect this. Thank you. Same result however. You are likely getting an error because Google Console has requests restricted from my domain.

The extractCalendarDateColors creates the JSON object with their fields: date, name, and color.

Comment: Tanaike, I checked GConsole errors for the Not Working script and I'm getting the same "Error: no such calendar". The calendar Id is the same in both Project Script Properties so I'm investigating why I'm not getting access to the calendar in the Not Working script (even though it Runs in debugger mode).

Comment: Tanaike, I found a problem. The callback I'm assuming is expecting javascript so I changed the GS to have: "return ContentService.createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(v) + ")").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);"

But now I'm getting a MIME Type exception: "Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." Am I not making the <script> call correctly? Should I be using $.ajax ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Tanaike for the inspiration on this problem. The CORB (cross origin error) was, as you mentioned above, likely to do with javascript call.

I updated the javascript: https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec?method=populate_events&year=2018

And updated the google script to use the parameters without throwing an error:

- e.parameter.method
- e.parameter.year

So it seems all the time I was getting the cross origin error, it was from a poorly formed javascript call and an error on the google script side, which returned an error and not a properly formed JSONP object.

**Thank you for your help Tanaike!! :)**

Comment: I'm really sorry for my late reply. But I could know your issue was solved. I'm glad for it. Thank you, too.